# Using eclipselink in Java code run from MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, eclipselink

I am trying to provide an interface that I can call from MATLAB to access the contents of a database. I already have an existing Java interface that uses eclipselink to connect to the database and I would like to re-use it. I wrote a class to provide this and it works properly when I call it straight from Java, but when I try to call it from MATLAB I get the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Perisistence provider for EntityManager named DatabaseConnection
```

Usually this exception occurs when I do not have the META-INF folder with the persistence.xml on the classpath properly, but I have tried putting the base folder that contains the META-INF folder on both the dynamic and static MATLAB javaclasspaths with no success. Again, this exact code (including the persistence.xml) work fine when run from java. Does anyone know what I am missing?

The one main difference that I was able to track down from what occurs when I run the java code is that MATLAB is using a OSGI classloader (felix) rather than the default classloader that Java uses, but I haven't figured out what difference that makes to finding the persistence.xml.

Comment: Probable dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376565/java-jpa-class-for-matlab. What are the odds of two Matlab/JPA/Eclipse/classpath questions in 24 hours? Do you work with Reilly? (Summary: put the eclipselink and your user JARs on the static classpath, too.)

Comment: I tried jarring up the code that I was working with (I had previously been pointing to the bin folder directly) along with the META-INF folder at the top level. I put this as the very first thing on the static classpath (in classpath.txt) along with a number of other jars that it is dependant on (including eclipselink). Unfortunately I got the same error.