# Adding several jar packages into DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

Tags: matlab, jar

I have a  question regarding adding several jar packages into Dynamic java path in Matlab. 
Having an instance of a java object (which is located in dynamic java path) I cannot  add another jar package correctly.

For instance:
If I have

> ```
>   DYNAMIC JAVA PATH
> ```

```
   ~/yamlmatlab/trunk/external/snakeyaml-1.9.jar
```

and one instance coming from the package

> yaml = org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml()

I cannot add another package correctly

> >>javaaddpath('myJarAchive.jar'] );
>
> Warning: Objects of org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml class exist - not clearing java
>
> In javaclasspath>doclear at 379
>
> In javaclasspath>local_javapath at 197
>
> In javaclasspath at 119
>
> In javaaddpath at 69
>
> In RcSession>RcSession.RcSession at 80

The objects from 'myJarAchive.jar' cannot be instantiated then.. Has anybody seen how to overcome this problem?

Thank you,

Jiri

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your JAR file contains the same yaml package, maybe you can extract the jar file (its a ZIP file after all), and selectively add the other classes you need..

Answer (score 0):

I never got the 'dynamic classpath' in MATLAB working as expected. Use the [ClassPathHacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580752/java-dynamically-loading-a-class/3581598#3581598) as shown for [eclipselink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434209/matlab-finds-persistence-xml-for-eclipselink-only-within-the-first-few-seconds/4436200#4436200) in order to add your jars dynamically.