# Matlab: using third-party java classes from within spmd

Tags: java, matlab, parallel-processing

I'm trying to use a class from a third-party Java library from within `spmd`, but I keep getting various errors related to importing it.

Here's a fairly minimal example:

```
spmd (1)
    javaaddpath([pwd 'lib/guava-10.0.1.jar']);
    import com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue;
    pq = MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();
end
```

This gives me the error

```
??? Error: MATLAB cannot determine whether "MinMaxPriorityQueue" refers to a
function or variable.
See <a href="matlab: helpview([docroot
'/toolbox/distcomp/distcomp_ug.map'],'SPMD_LIMITATIONS')">SPMD in MATLAB,
"Limitations"</a>.
```

(Of course, [that "Limitations" document](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/brukbnp-9.html#brukbnp-12) doesn't seem to have anything particularly relevant.)

Moving the `javaaddpath` and/or the `import` outside of the `spmd` block doesn't help; doing it without an `import` but instead just saying `pq = com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue.create` results in it giving the same error about `com`.

Calling an anonymous function defined outside the `spmd` block gives a different error:

```
javaaddpath([pwd '/lib/guava-10.0.1.jar']);
make_pq = @() com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();
spmd (1)
    javaaddpath([pwd '/lib/guava-10.0.1.jar']);
    pq = make_pq();
end
```

gets me

```
The class "com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue" is undefined.
Perhaps Java is not running.
```

But Java is definitely running, because

```
spmd (1)
   pq = java.util.PriorityQueue();
end
```

and

```
spmd (1)
    javaaddpath([pwd '/lib']);
    pq = ArrayPriorityComparator.create();
end
```

work (`ArrayPriorityComparator` is a standalone java class in `./lib`).

This feels to me like a problem with Matlab's parsing of the `spmd` block. But I don't think I can use `javaObject()` or `javaMethod()` to work around it, since I have to call a static method to create the object, and I can't just throw it in an `eval` because I get a `Transparency violation error` (or, if I put it in an anonymous function defined outside the `spmd`, I get the same `class is undefined` error).

Any ideas? Real solutions or horrible awful hacks are both welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is another 'dynamic classpath' issue. Refer to [Bringing Java Classes and Methods into MATLAB Workspace](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f4863.html) on how to use the 'static classpath'.

In cases where you won't depend on the static classpath use the method described in the following posts.

- [MATLAB finds persistence.xml for eclipselink only within the first few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4436200/426834)
- [Java JPA Class for MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4380605/426834)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pctRunOnAll` to set the java path?

I'm afraid I don't have a convenient cluster to test on to see if that would work.

Comment: Same results (class undefined if I do it in an anonymous function, cannot determine whether function or variable if it's directly in the `spmd` block). I don't really see why it would be different than just doing the `javaaddpath` in the `spmd` block anyway...though I guess with matlab you never know.

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a try. If you're lucky, @EdricEllis will turn up and give you the right answer.

Comment: Hmm, that was going to be my suggestion. Shame it doesn't work. Javaaddpath has to do some crazy stuff, maybe that's why it doesn't work.