# matlab java class path issue

Tags: java, matlab, dynamic, static, classpath

When I put classpaths into the static class path (ie put them in the classpath.txt file) program works. When I add it dynamically, I get an error that it can't find a properties file in the class path.

Here is what I have

> javaaddpath('C:\exchsys\jars\exsystools.jar')
>   javaaddpath('C:\exchsys\externaljars\log4j.jar')
>   javaaddpath('C:\exchsys\externaljars\')
>   javaaddpath('C:\apache-activemq-5.1.0\lib\commons-logging-1.1.jar')
>   javaaddpath('C:\apache-activemq-5.1.0\activemq-all-5.1.0.jar')

plus my actual code

This leads to the following error:
javax.naming.ConfigurationException: JMSUtilities.loadConfiguration(): Properties file "/exsysjms.properties" not found in the classpath.

The file it is looking for is a in the folder added through this line

> javaaddpath('C:\exchsys\externaljars\')

When I put the same paths into the classpath.txt file it works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your experiencing issues concerning *static* vs *dynamic classpath*. A workaround for this issue is shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376565/java-jpa-class-for-matlab/4380605#4380605) by using `ClassPathHacker.java` in order to dynamically load java classes. You may check the other responses as well for further information.

Comment: yes I was able to get it to work with the static. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the actual java files nor can I put the paths into the static path as this is to be a compiled program that will run on a different computer

Comment: The *ClassPathHacker* approach works as compiled version as well.