# Does R lock jar or DLL files?

Tags: java, r, dll, jar

Now that I've discovered another wonderful feature of Matlab [and its handling of jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539586/matlab-locks-the-jar-file-when-i-try-to-call-java-methods-from-it),  I'd like to know how `R`  deals with jar and dll files.  Does anyone know, or have a link to a detailed manual, how `R` works with jar files and whether there are lock/release problems?

Comment: mmm... Did you look at rJava package?

Comment: Link: http://tuxette.nathalievilla.org/?p=940

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes, but not in great detail because I'm not a java programmer and unlikely to understand the implications of the help file. Edit: your linked example might be of use if I understood exactly what objects or files are being unlinked.

Comment: I've used rJava once, it worked for me. But never with dynamic jars, where your problem lies IIUC. Try to write some code snippet and update the question, I would say...