# Loading Java class from website with newInstance?

Tags: java

The workings of my program:

1. Connect to server
2. Get String
3. Decrypt String
4. Send it back

I'm decrypting with a class i downloaded from the server. The class changes everytime and should be downloaded everytime i start my program

It HAS! to be in package named etc/etc/client/file.class

It works flawless when i'm testing it INSIDE eclipse cause the package folder is then accesible

But what do i do when i want to export is as runnable .jar ? Then i can't write in the package folder?

The line that's loading the class:
(The class extends Base64 which is already in the folder)

```
etc.sec.client.Base64 decode = (etc.sec.client.Base64)Class.forName("etc.sec.client." + handlerClass).newInstance();
// Handler class is the name of the class
```

The folder i'm downloading the class to before loading `newInstance()`:

```
bin/etc/sec/client/"+filename+".class
```

Works perfect in eclipse but i do not know how to make it work when exporting to .jar

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load the class using a new class loader.

```
public void go() throws Exception {
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("file:///home/ben/") }, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class decoderclass = cl.loadClass("etc.sec.client." + handlerClass);
    etc.sec.client.Base64 decode = (etc.sec.client.Base64)decoderclass.newInstance();
    System.out.println(decode.toString());
}
```

If download your class into:

```
/home/ben/etc/sec/client/
```

That should instantiate the class fine. Naturally you will have to use the interface available at compile time, `etc.sec.client.Base64` must be an interface or your handler class must inherit from it.

Comment: This question has a nice loader implementation you should look at: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580752/java-dynamically-loading-a-class)