# How to run clojure from matlab

Tags: matlab, clojure, classpath

How can I run a clojure script from matlab?

I tried following:
run matlab with jdk 1.7 and then call java

```
MATLAB_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre matlab
```

in the matlab, set classpath and use clojure compiler

```
javaaddpath([pwd '/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar'])
import clojure.lang.RT
```

Here I got error:

```
Error using import
Import argument 'clojure.lang.RT' cannot be found or cannot be imported.
```

When I writing java class that runs clojure, everything  working from console, but whould not run from matlab. 
please advice.

Comment: From what I remember, Matlab will have problems if you want to use classes or java packages compiled using different java version that the one which is included with Matlab (i.e. 1.6).

Comment: That's why he's using MATLAB_JAVA, i guess. This should make matlab use the jvm pointed to, rather than the one included in MATLAB. And, since this appears to be on a linux-system: MATLAB only brings its own jre on windows, afaik.

Comment: Since you say you want to run a script, rather than call Clojure functions or something like that, couldn't you do it with `system`?

Comment: That is workaround that I did. Run clojure in separated process using system and saved result as java object in temp file. Then from matlab read this file. ugly, but working.

Comment: What OS, OS version, and Matlab version are you running?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is a problem with Clojure not being happy running from Matlab's "dynamic classpath". I got the same error with Matlab R2014a on OS X 10.9, using either the bundled JVM or Java 1.7.0u51. But if I add `clojure-1.5.1.jar` to the static classpath by putting it in a custom `javaclasspath.txt` in the Matlab startup directory, then the Clojure classes become visible.

```
>> version -java
ans =
Java 1.7.0_51-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
>> cloj = clojure.lang.RT
cloj =
clojure.lang.RT@77de6590
```

#### Hacking the Java classpath

You use the "class path hacking" approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime) to add entries to the static classpath from the Matlab command line and not have to muck around with a custom Matlab setup. The answer there involves writing a new Java class, but you can do the equivalent in pure M-code.

```
function javaaddpathstatic(file)
%JAVAADDPATHSTATIC Add an entry to the static classpath at run time
%
% javaaddpathstatic(file)
%
% Adds the given file to the STATIC classpath. This is in contrast to the
% regular javaaddpath, which adds a file to the dynamic classpath.
%
% Files added to the path will not show up in the output of
% javaclasspath(), but they will still actually be on there, and classes
% from it will be picked up.
%
% Caveats:
% * This is a HACK and bound to be unsupported.
% * You need to call this before attempting to reference any class in it,
%   or Matlab may "remember" that the symbols could not be resolved.
% * There is no way to remove the new path entry once it is added.

parms = javaArray('java.lang.Class', 1);
parms(1) = java.lang.Class.forName('java.net.URL');
loaderClass = java.lang.Class.forName('java.net.URLClassLoader');
addUrlMeth = loaderClass.getDeclaredMethod('addURL', parms);
addUrlMeth.setAccessible(1);

sysClassLoader = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

argArray = javaArray('java.lang.Object', 1);
jFile = java.io.File(file);
argArray(1) = jFile.toURI().toURL();
addUrlMeth.invoke(sysClassLoader, argArray);
```

So, use this `javaaddpathstatic()` instead of `javaaddpath()` and your code might work.

Comment: Discussed in some detail here: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/static-java-classpath-hacks