# Adding jar file to classpath at runtime without reflection tricks

Tags: java, classloader

There are several posts about how to add jar-file to classpath at runtime by following idea:
- get current system classpath;
- suppose it is URLClassLoader;
- use reflection to set access for protected addURL method;
- use mentioned method to add url to classpath.

Here is an example:
[Adding files to java classpath at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime)

Because of 2 and 3 steps this looks like "nasty hack".

How could I extend URLClassLoader and set it as a current? I am bit confused with classloaders and tried the following:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file:jxl.jar")});
    System.out.println(loader.loadClass("jxl.Workbook"));
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
    System.out.println(Class.forName("jxl.Workbook"));
} // main
```

I get ClassNotFoundException on the fourth line, while second works ok. (why it is so, by the way?)

Answer (score 2):

The `Class.forName` method uses the "defining class loader of the current class," not the thread context classloader. In your case the `ClassLoader` that `Class.forName` will use is the one that loaded your application, i.e. the [system class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader%28%29). This is a class loader that looks for resources in the class path.

Comment: Ah... thank you... I forgot of it. But what if I change fourth line to: System.out.println(jxl.Workbook.class); - surely I should provide import jxl.* while compilation - it would not work on runtime either.

Comment: In that case you would need to have jxl.Workbook in the classpath to compile. If you tried to execute without jxl.Workbook the JVM would throw a NoClassDefFoundError when loading your class

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is different kind of error. I think it is bit clearer now. Thank you for your explanation!