# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver during Dynamic Web Project creation in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am designing a registration page using MVC design pattern. I have made a class file which will input the parameters into the database using sql commands but i am getting

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Here is the code

```
package src.service;

import java.sql.*;

public class RegisterService {

    public void addToDatabase(String name, String id, String email, String     password){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            // Get a connection to the database
            Connection myConn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chillmaarodb", "root", "rsystems");

            // Create a statement

            Statement myStatement = myConn.createStatement();

            String sql = "insert into userid values(" + id + ", '" + name + "', '" + email + "', '" + password + "')";

            myStatement.executeUpdate(sql); 


        }

        catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

I have imported the driver in my lib folder of the project, imported it in build path, imported it in tomcat server in the folder tomcatv7>lib by creating a lib folder. Still it is showing the same error. Kindly help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (in jre's libs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602899/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-jres-libs)

Comment: JDBC driver JARs belong in the Tomcat server /lib folder.  It sounds like you created a subfolder /lib/lib.  Don't do that.

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar is present in classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the DB Connection in server.xml
follow this tutorial :
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mysql-connector-for-java-how-to-install-in-eclipse-and-tomcat/
and
https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-mysql

as well as you need to download MySQL Connector from:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
and copy the jar file to "C:\tomcat7\lib"

Answer (score 1):

You should add `MYSQL JDBC LIBRARY` to your project
and also import

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

Comment: i have imported java.sql.* without any compile time error but in my libraries folder there is no such mysqllibrary.

Comment: if no libraray found. you should download the jar file (JDBC driver JAR).     are you using NETBEANS IDE ?

Comment: actually there was a problem in connection of tomcat and jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me---

**This solution is only for Dynamic web projects.**

Steps--

1)Create a Dynamic Web project

2)I added the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin" jar in **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib** folder.

2) Create a tomcat server

3)inside src create a demo servlet--

```
package com.luv2code.testdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestDbServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestDbServlet")
public class TestDbServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // setup connection variables
        String user = "springstudent";
        String pass = "springstudent";

        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        // get connection to database
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            out.println("Connecting to database: " + jdbcUrl);

            Class.forName(driver);

            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, pass);

            out.println("SUCCESS!!!");

            myConn.close();

        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }


    }

}
```

4)**Just right click and run as run on server select ur tomact server**

Remember before all these you need to create ur db schema,
here i have used mysql workbench.
Mysql part is not covered in this answer.

If this does not work, try adding the msql connector jar inside **tomcat/lib** folder