# load external jar in to class path for java project

Tags: java, jar, classpath, buildpath, eclipse-classpath

I have a lib folder at installer location that i want to load at class path or refrenced at runtime for my java project, programmaticaly.

I have tried to set classpath by `-cp` and used `ClassLoader`, `URLClassLoader` but it did't work. found `ClassNotFoundException`. I also tried static block to load my jar.

How to resolve it, how can we referenced external jar folder dynamically or can load it at class path.

I am using Eclipse IDE which have option in build path to load external folder but i am not sure it will work when i export the project as it is building path for my current workspace only so it would't work when installer go in others machine. So i required to load that folder programatically.

Comment: it seem that you're ready to start using maven...

Comment: @Guy but currently i am not using maven, can i have solution for this without maven.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [environmental](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) variable to load the class or jar.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at these questions in stackoverflow it self. they may help you. I personally haven't tried and never came across this kind of requirement.

[How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

[Loading jars at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624907/loading-jars-at-runtime)

Hope above links help you to solve your problem.

Comment: not working, first i need to resolve compile time error that i resolved by build path->add external folder. Now i used classLoader and and reflection to load at runtime while application invokes. I have doubt both are creating conflict and the jar resolved at compile time certain to do some thing when loading by class loader at runtime.