# Java multiple jar applications into 1

Tags: java

I have many java applications with gui and standalone works fine.

I would like to implement an application that when runned, it will load all applications available into a panel and the user can choose an applcation to execute.

Can this be done? And if yes how?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Yes, it can be done.

Comment: How can this be done?

Comment: Ah! Here's the rub - we're not a free code writing service. You need to _attempt_ something, tell us why it doesn't work and what your issues are - with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). As it stands, this question is off topic here...

Comment: Ok I will try it and post again :)

Answer (score 0):

Every application is a stand alone application right ? 
so Its possible you can place it in a pane and invoke it onclick, its doable.

Answer (score 0):

What you would want is to create a new jar, create that panel that displays each different app (say with a button), and once the button is pressed, call an operation to have it load that specific jar file. You can read here for more info  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624907/loading-jars-at-runtime)