# Place and access a file in class path after the main class is loaded

Tags: java

I have an executable Jar file. This jar extracts a tar file and provides a Jar and an empty configuration file. My executable Jar populates the empty configuration file and calls the main method of extracted jar. The called main method looks for the configuration file in class path. Now the problem is the populated configuration file is not in the class path, instead its in some other directory.

How can I place it to class path and make sure it is loaded properly and accessible to the extracted jar?

Comment: Where will be the configuration file exist? The same directory where the extracted jar?

Comment: Yes..In the same directory where the extracted jar exists. But the executable jar is in some other directory.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried?

you can move file using
    file.renameTo(new File("<new Path>"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the directory where the file will eventually be placed to the JVMs classpath when starting it, i.e. using

```
java -jar -classpath <path-with-jars-and-your-directory> app.jar
```

Unless you run the extracted jar in a different JVM, you will have to give the right classpath when running the executable jar that does the extracting.

Another option is using a custom [`ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html). You can create one that adds the right directory to its search path and [use it as context classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setContextClassLoader-java.lang.ClassLoader-). More hints can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16564582/1267168).