# Dynamically load top-level class in a jar outside of classpath

Tags: java, jar, classloader, dynamically-generated, dynamic-class-loaders

**UPDATE** - All of the files in my project now declare the same package.  However, the jar I'm loading has to be outside of the classpath.  I've tried `child.loadClass(className)` and `Class.forName(className, false, child);`, but neither of them seem to be able to find it.

I'm writing a program that wants to take plugins or modules in the form of jars and use them as if they were embedded in the classpath.

I've seen a lot of similar questions on here and other sites, so I apologize for the duplication.  But, so far, every answer I've seen hasn't worked.  Am I doing something wrong?

I have a folder full of jars.  I know that each jar has one top-level class that extends my Module class.  But, I don't know what those classes are called.

First, I find all the files in the directory.  That works fine.  Then, for each file, I try to get an instance of its top-level class using the following code:

(First it opens the jar as a zip to get the names of all the classes, then looks at the name to tell if it's a top-level class, then, if so, is supposed to load, instantiate and return it.)

```
private static Module jarLoader(String jar){
    try{
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(ModulesDir+"/"+jar));
        URL[] myJarFile = new URL[]{new URL("jar","","file:"+ModulesDir)};
        URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJarFile , Main.class.getClassLoader());
        for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
            if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                // This ZipEntry represents a class. Now, what class does it represent?
                String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.'); // including ".class"
                className = className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length());


                String[] classNameParts = className.replace('$', ':').split(":");//I don't know why i have to do this, but it won't split on "$"
                if(classNameParts.length == 1){
                    System.out.println("trying to load "+className);
                    Class classToLoad = Class.forName(className, false, child);
                    System.out.println("loaded class "+classToLoad.getName());
                    if(classToLoad.getSuperclass() == Module.class){
                        Module instance = (Module) classToLoad.newInstance();
                        return instance;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        zip.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It gets as far as "trying to load ..." and it shows the name of the class as I would expect it to, and then throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Using the same name to load the class worked fine when i put it in a .java file in the source dir, but it wont get it from a jar.

Am I doing something wrong? I suspect the class name may need some kind of prefix or suffix but I cant figure out what.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: classname will require its full package name also

Comment: @JunedAhsan I guessed that but I didn't know what package name to use since I didn't specify one in the jars.  Is there a default or is my only option to declare a package in each jar?

Comment: Did u put all the jars  under your class path? Class.forName() will search current classpath, that's the one specified with '-classpath' para when running 'java.exe'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that was suggested didn't seem to work because the files i needed to load were outside my classpath.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460999/1115876) works though

Answer (score 0):

`throw ClassNotFoundException` is that your load jar file not be added in class path, and the below code not successfully load your jar file.

```
URL[] myJarFile = new URL[]{new URL("jar","","file:"+ModulesDir)};
        URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJarFile , Main.class.getClassLoader());
```

it should be like:

```
   URL[] myJarFile = new URL[]{new URL("jar","",jarFilePath)};

   URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJarFile, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

and when `javac` compile class, the inner class will be expressed in the full path and split by *$*, such as `com/hello/world/TT$InnerClass.class`.

The full sample:

```
 private void jarLoader(){
        try{
            String ModulesDir = "./test/test.jar";
            ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(ModulesDir));

            URL[] myJarFile = new URL[]{new URL("jar","",ModulesDir)};

            URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJarFile , this.getClass().getClassLoader());

            for (ZipEntry entry = zip.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = zip.getNextEntry()) {
                if (!entry.isDirectory() && entry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                    // This ZipEntry represents a class. Now, what class does it represent?
                    String className = entry.getName().replace('/', '.'); // including ".class"
                    className = className.substring(0, className.length() - ".class".length());


                    String[] classNameParts = className.replace('$', ':').split(":");//I don't know why i have to do this, but it won't split on "$"
                    if(classNameParts.length == 1){
                        System.out.println("trying to load "+className);
                        Class classToLoad = Class.forName(className, true, child);
                        System.out.println("loaded class "+classToLoad.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
            zip.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```