# How do I call a method within another jar file

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I noticed that a minecraft server loads in external `jar` files. I would like to use this to create a hub to load small games into. I want to do this by calling a method in a group of `jar` files to load them. Is this possible without executing it directly or modifying the classpath. I'm using the following code to start and load the hub:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I will run a loop for the number of jar files in a folder. I will store these in an array. Then I want the action for the button to call a load method from the `jar` files

Comment: Can you post some code samples what you are trying to work on?

Comment: I want to run a loop to create JButton objects for each jar file. And then call a load method from them

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the jar to your buildpath of the project, right click the project
2. Select "Build Path" option
3. Select "Configure Build Path" and add in the external jar

Once you've configured your buildpath you import the class, create an instance of the class to use whatever method you're looking for. That should be it.

I think you can also do something like this (once it's added to your buildpath), not 100% sure on this one though.

```
ClassNameFromJarYouWant.MethodYouWant();
```

That'd be the easiest.

But if you really need to be able to add the JARs without modifying the classpath look up [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). Here's a post I found that might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime) you.