# how to add a file to Java Classpath at Runtime?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am creating a feature file at runtime and trying to access the file once it is created . I have followed all the methods given  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010919/adding-files-to-java-classpath-at-runtime) .

```
 1. Is there a way to refresh the project at runtime ?
 2. Is there any other way to load the file in classpath ?
```

[Edit] Adding Sample code

```
  public static void createFeatureFile(String featurePath) throws IOException{

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(featurePath);

    writer.append("Feature: Test ");
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("@test");
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("Scenario : add fruits");
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("Given I have 1 apple and 1 orange");
    writer.append("\n");
    writer.append("Then I add both"");
    writer.append("\n");                    

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();    

    File file =new File(featurePath);
    addFileAtRunTime(file);           

}

  private static void addFileAtRunTime(File file) throws Exception {
        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
    }
```

Comment: You should look into custom classloaders.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one on for size.

```
   private static void addFileAtRunTime(File file) throws Exception {
        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
    }
```

This edits the system class loader to include the given file.